# Getting a "Network Error" with Axios in React when making GET/PUT requests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am working on a project in React, using Axios to communicate with my API. I have created a functional component in which I am making a GET/PUT request to my API. However, I am running into a "Network Error" when I try to execute the request. Additionally, I am seeing the error message "Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead." in my console.

Here is the code for my Home component:

> Home.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import './Home.css'
import Courses from './Courses';
import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
import Title from '../components/Title';
import axios from 'axios';
export default function Home() {
const reqBody = {
name:"Roee",
idNumber:"132456789",
idNumberConf:"132456789",
personalNumber:"1234567",
personalNumberConf:"1234567",
hogerNumber:"12345678",
hogerNumberConf:"12345678",
phoneNumber:"054838350",
birthDate:"06/12/1990",
password:"1132456",
passwordConf:"1132456"};

const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};

const reqFunc = async () => {
    console.log("ddd");
    axios.get('localhost:3010/accounts/mine', reqBody, config).then((res) => {
    console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ", res);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
    })
    
    
}

      return (
    <>
        <div className="bg"></div>
        <Title title={"Search for Course"}/>
        <SearchBar/>
        {reqFunc()} 
        <Courses/>
        </>
);
}
```

> App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route,Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from './pages/Home';
import Courses from './pages/Courses'
import Navbar from './components/Navbar'
import Signin from './pages/Sign-in'
import Register from './pages/Register'
import ErrorPage from './components/ErrorPage'
import SingleCourse from './pages/SingleCourse'
import './App.css'
import {
  MDBContainer,
} from 'mdbreact';
import Footer from './components/Footer'
function App() {
  return (
      <>
  
  <Navbar/>
  <MDBContainer fluid>      
  <Switch>

    <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
    <Route exact path="/courses" component={Courses}/>
    <Route exact path="/courses/:id" component={SingleCourse}/>
    <Route path="/log-in" component={Signin}/>
    <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
    <Route component={ErrorPage}/>
  </Switch>
  
  </MDBContainer>
  <Footer/>
  </>


);
}

export default App;
```

> I got an Error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

in Home (created by Context.Consumer)
in Route (at App.js:24)
in Switch (at App.js:22)
in div (created by Container)
in Container (at App.js:21)
in App (at src/index.js:12)
in Router (created by BrowserRouter)
in BrowserRouter (at src/index.js:11)
```

> Also the err log to the console

```
Home.js:36 AXIOS ERROR:  Error: Network Error
at createError (createError.js:17)
at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:80)
at dispatchXhrRequest (xhr.js:166)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at xhrAdapter (xhr.js:16)
at dispatchRequest (dispatchRequest.js:49)
```

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve the "Network Error" and the issue with the error message in the console. Thank you!

Comment: First log error: Never do that into `render` method `{reqFunc()} `, if you won't return a React component. You can use React lifecycle instead. https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-lifecycle-methods-to-a-class

Comment: The second, you're using `axios.get(url[, config])` wrong. If you want to `send data`, use `axios.post()` instead. https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosposturl-data-config-1

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const reqFunc = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(
      "localhost:3010/accounts/mine",
      reqBody,
      config
    );
    console.log(response);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};
```

You're not 'await'ing anything in your async function, so the async part is redundant in your example.

The first error is because your promise hasn't fully resolved.

Comment: The problem starts with calling to async code inside render. You should only place html elements inside it. Your auggestion will solve the problem since it will return undefined instead of promise but he ahould understand the root cause.

Comment: And the problem with your solution is that you don't actually provide one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can answer your questions but I have a few comments.
I'm working more with fetch API and my comments work with fetch API so here also can be useful regarding that axios and fetch are similar.
This is not in a valid JSON format: `const reqBody`
I would write like this:

```
const reqBody = {
"name":"Roee",
"idNumber":"132456789",
"idNumberConf":"132456789",
"personalNumber":"1234567",
"personalNumberConf":"1234567",
"hogerNumber":"12345678",
"hogerNumberConf":"12345678",
"phoneNumber":"0548336350",
"birthDate":"06/12/1990",
"password":"1132456",
"passwordConf":"1132456"}
```

HTTP Get request should not take a request body or it is a typo and you meant POST request :

```
axios.post('localhost:3010/accounts/mine', reqBody, config)
```

and I would say for the content type can be application/json :

```
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your call in a `useEffect` hook and try this:

```
  const [data, updateData] = useState(undefined);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get('localhost:3010/accounts/mine', reqBody, config);
      const json = await response.json();
      updateData(json);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem in your case is that you are calling your fetch code inside the render return statment. Try to call the function before you return.